# Using Google Forms to write to multiple tables?

Tags: python, sql, google-forms

I am creating a web project where I take in Form data and write to a SQL database.
The forms will be a questionnaire with logic branching. Due to the nature of the form, and the fact that this is an MVP project, I've opted to use an existing form service (e.g Google Forms/Typeform).

I was wondering if it's feasible to have form data submitted to multiple different tables (e.g CustomerInfo, FormDataA, FormDataB, etc.). While this might be possible with a custom form application, I do not think it's possible with Google Forms and/or Typeform.

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how to parse user submitted Form data into multiple tables when using Google Forms or Typeform?**

Comment: Data being written to a Google Form can't be interrupted.  So you would need to get the data out of the Google Form, then divide it up.  Probably the easiest way to do that would be with Apps Script.  Apps Script can make HTTPS GET and POST requests with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`, so you could send the data out with that.  There is no REST API to connect from python to a Google Form.  But you can make an HTTPS GET or POST request to either a `doGet()` or `doPost()` function in a stand alone Apps Script project, and then Apps Script can do what you want.

Comment: I was either thinking of this approach, or dumping and querying everything in google sheets and dividing the responses up into different worksheets. However, I only think Google sheets would parse the information when I open it up (and not automatically).
Alternatively, wouldn't I be able to just post these responses to a master table in SQL and then run table queries to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script in the Google spreadsheet with an onsubmit trigger. Then you can do whatever you want with the submitted data.